# Structuring a c++ linux program. When to break out separate files vs separate programs

Tags: c++, linux, architecture

Fairly new to c/c++. I am writing some code for my RaPi and in .net this would be easy for me, but I am fighting with the design a bit in c++.

In short, when should I break up code from main vs another cpp file vs a separate program?

Currently I have 2 programs that talk to each other via a socket fifo.

**PiSocket** - All internet communication. Put's, Get's and a signalR connection. Along with sending and receiving data from MainPi.

**MainPi** - Sends and receives data with PiSocket, deals with the database and executing system commands (such as pulling/sending gpio data).

What I am not sure on:
There are basically 4 pieces of code. Main loop, internet connection, database calls and system commands. When/how should they be broken out? I doubt all the code combined will be much more than 20k lines, but it does have to be fairly real time communication (within a couple seconds).

Using a socket to communicate seems messy, so I am thinking each piece should be its own cpp file. At the same time, would it be a cyclical redundancy having PiSocket.cpp reference MainPi and vise versa? Or should I make a call to each piece from an infinite loop in main with its own thread? There will also be code updates via the web/PiSocket, which may matter, tho I doubt.

Sure this is simple enough, but my searches didn't reveal much and really don't want to have to redesign this later.

Thanx ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're conflating two separate issues:

- .cpp files imply a separate C++ translation unit, which results in a separate object/library file that may or may not link in other objects already built
- .cpp files with their own `main()` can produce separate executable programs, which run in their own process

You only need IPC mechanisms such as sockets / FIFO when you have separate processes.  There's nothing in your problem description that suggests that would be useful for you.

If I were you, I'd write "piSocket.cpp" as an Internet connectivity library: it could use threads to do comms/processing in the background, and the calls from the code in "main.cpp" could stipulate functions to be called when reportable events happen (e.g. data arrives from the Internet).  You'd also need a "piSocket.h" file - typically with typedefs, constants, enums, function declarations, class definitions, templates and/or inline functions associated with the "piSocket" comms functionality.  That header should be included by both piSocket.cpp and mainPi.cpp.

Details vary with compilers, but the basic build process might look something like:

```
# compile piSocket.cpp into piSocket.o
g++ -c piSocket.cpp

# compile mainPi.cpp and link in piSocket.o to form myApp executable
g++ -o myApp mainPi.cpp piSocket.o
```

All up, I'd say this will cause you pain.  A good alternative is to leave everything in one file, and learn enough about the language to get the functionality working first, then worry about splitting the file's content in two.  If you can't get the functionality working, there's no point understanding about better "physical design" (separation into files).

Comment: Thanks. That's about what I figured. Not sure why the previous dev made 2 separate programs. Sounds like every major functional area should be in its own cpp file which makes more sense than the way it's done now..